# can i have multiple similar features derived from same properties in a dataset?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, feature-engineering

Say I am fitting a (linear) regression model to a hundred-row dataset, whose data records a series of experiments that I can hardly reproduce or further conduct to get more records, I notice that there are multiple columns/features *x1, ..., xn* that are essentially derivation of a more fundamental property named *X*.

Now, obviously it is natural to only record *X* if possible, however, due to the limit of the experiment, *X* is impossible to directly measure, and therefore we have to seek other approaches that measure *X* under their coordianates. Note that different observation systems on *X* could have different numerical values. This is where it confused me, since different representations on *X* seems statistically irrelevant, in a way that each pair of those features do not have a strong correlation (coeff. > 0.9), is it acceptable to keep all those features (approximately 5 to 10) in my dataset, without worrying about "over-emphasize" the importance of *X*?

I also thought about only keeping one of those features, either arbitrarily or through a more strict statistical analysis, however, this would significantly reduce the dimension of my data, which seems quite risky, as I do not have many other features to work with.

Any suggestion on the situaion?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of your data.

If you have a massive sample size and your variables have low noise, adding more variables  will make your model better.

If you have a tiny sample size and your variables are very noisy, adding more variables will lead to wild overfitting.

When you add in a variable, your are hoping that the information your model gains offsets it's new capacity to overfit the data through the added dimensionality.

Imagine I'm trying to predict house price and I have neighborhood quality, proximity to downtown core, floor area, house volume, house height, house weight, and house width. If my dataset is small, I'll probably keep the neighborhood quality, distance to downtown and floor area and ditch the rest, because I'd expect that much of the underlying information about house size (as you call it, X) is covered by the floor area. Alternatively I may consider doing PCA to preserve the information in all these X-related variables but with the lowest added dimensionality possible.

But if I had a giant dataset, I'll add all these weird house size-related variables because they still have information in them and I have a sample size big enough to not overfit the data too badly.

If you want to know for your specific dataset what's appropriate you may want to consider evaluating regression models built with different numbers of these features through cross validation. I'd recommend taking a look at chapter 2 and 6 (6 especially on model selection) of the Introduction to Statistical Learning book to see the problem here formalized a bit better and practical advice on how to determine the right number of features to include. The book is free here https://www.statlearning.com/ and there are YouTube videos where the authors walk through each of the chapters in detail.

Comment: For a variable of low noise, I assume you mean a general fit to normal distribution and low correlation to other variables? If that's the case, then yes, all those features I mentioned above, though derived from the same property, pass this criteria. The interesting thing is, my dataset is relatively small( 270 entries, 180 of which come from pretty much exactly same setting with minimal modification), so I am still undecided whether to keep those features or not..

Comment: By noise I'm referring to how much of the values in the feature are impossible for your dataset to explain. This is something explained quite well in chapter 2 of the book I linked.

Comment: When deciding on keeping the features or not, nobody can say for certain what will be best based on the information you've provided. IMO this is the "golden" question for basic statistical modelling - there no easy automatic rule for answering this yet. If you read the highlighted chapters of the book I linked, you will learn a lot that will help you answer this and similar problems in the future. And this scenario you are in really will come up all the time. Also there is some subjectivity to including features - don't get too caught up in trying to find one perfect optimal solution.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I will look into it!